# Get recipient view not working for composite envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create a composite envelope and then do an embedded signing.  The issue is that the envelope is created but the call to get the url fails.

First I create the composite envelope:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT/envelopes
{
"emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
"emailBlurb": "Composite Templates Sample 1",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "1AA7BA0B-9079-4F8C-915B-739576297D62"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "email@email.com",
                            "name": "Signer Name",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Account Holder"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "templateId": "77343ECC-391F-46A1-BFC3-92A3CD8C93E3"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "email@email.com",
                            "name": "Signer Name",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Account Holder",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "AccountFirstName",
                                        "value": "Client"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "AccountLastName",
                                        "value": "Name"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "Email1",
                                        "value": "someEmail@email.com"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "3",
                "templateId": "ADADDD87-E831-4EF3-A160-BBE73F449C8E"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "3",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "email@email.com",
                            "name": "Signer Name",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Account Holder"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The response is:

```
{
"envelopeId": "99f4c73d-6420-4e3b-88eb-2447139a2616",
"uri": "/envelopes/99f4c73d-6420-4e3b-88eb-2447139a2616",
"statusDateTime": "2014-08-14T21:09:09.0430000Z",
"status": "sent"   }
```

Next I try to get the recipient view

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT/envelopes/99f4c73d-6420-4e3b-88eb-2447139a2616/views/recipient
{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "returnUrl": "www.someUrl.com",
  "userName": "Signer Name"
}
```

And I get this error:

```
{
"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
"message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified      envelope. Envelope recipient could not be determined. 'clientUserId', 'email', or 'userName' in request and envelope may not match."
}
```

The email and the names match up so I do not understand why I am unable to get the url.  I should point out that this all works if I use the same name and email that is on the DocuSign account, but this needs to work for an external recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To designate a recipient as an embedded/captive recipient when creating an Envelope, such that you'll subsequently be able to submit a "Get Recipient View" request to retrieve a URL that can be used to initiate the recipient's signing session, your "Create Envelope" request must specify the **clientUserId** property for the recipient.  This property should appear as a peer to the other recipient properties (i.e.: email, name, etc.) -- like this:

```
"signers": [
    {
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "name": "Signer Name",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "Account Holder",
        "clientUserId": "12345"
    }
]
```

Then, when you submit the "Get Recipient View" request, you'll need to specify the same value for **clientUserId** there:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/views/recipient

{
  "authenticationMethod": "Email",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "returnUrl": "www.someUrl.com",
  "userName": "Signer Name",
  "clientUserId": "12345"
}
```

The value of **clientUserId** can be anything you wish, but max length is 100 characters. See the [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for more details about embedded signing.

Comment: Glad I could help out.  Can you please mark this Answer as "Accepted" (so that it shows the green checkmark), so that others may benefit from this information in the future?  Thank you!